# Preserving all sheets while copying data from another workbook

Tags: python, pandas

How can I preserve all other sheets while copying data from another workbook?

This code deletes all the other existing sheets :

```
my_path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Desktop//Autoreport//Load_attachments//'
my_path1 =r'C://Users//greencolor/Desktop//Autoreport//'
for filename in os.listdir(my_path):
    if filename.startswith('PB orders Dec'):
        dec = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(my_path, filename), 
                                         sheet_name='Raw data ', 
                                         engine='pyxlsb')
        dec.to_excel(my_path1 + '//Report.xlsx',sheet_name='DecData', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you specify more information: this is quite a short, brief post...

Comment: I have a Master file called Report.xlsx I have a sheet there named DecData. which has to update on weekly basis. I would like to take data from another workbeek and paste it on Decdata sheet without deleteing other sheets in Report.xlsx file

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExcelWriter`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(my_path1 + '//Report.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:  
    dec.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DecData', index=False)
```

Comment: I get an error-> io.UnsupportedOperation: truncate

Comment: What is your version of Pandas? Is `openpyxl` installed? force `engine=openpyxl` as parameter of `ExcelWriter`.

Comment: 1.2.4 pandas, when I change a mode = 'w+' it works and deletes all other sheets

Comment: I get this error now: ValueError: No Excel writer '<module 'openpyxl' from 'C:\\Users

Comment: openpyxl is installed

Comment: What is the result when you use `pd.ExcelWriter(..., mode='a', engine='openpyxl')`?

Comment: Error message - ValueError: No Excel writer '<module 'openpyxl' from 'C:\\Users ....

Comment: Check the output of `pd.show_versions()`

Comment: The bug you have is typically an issue of xlsxwriter engine.

Comment: pandas           : 1.2.4
numpy            : 1.21.3
pytz             : 2021.3
dateutil         : 2.8.2
pip              : 21.1.2
setuptools       : 57.0.0                                                                                                                  openpyxl         : 3.0.9                                                                                                                 pyxlsb           : 1.0.9

Comment: I just installed Xlsxwrtiter too but still have same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240256/discussion-between-greencolor-and-corralien).